# How to Identify Toilet Tank Brand for Replacement?

Tags: bathroom, water, toilet, replacement, usa

My toilet tank broke after I was trying to perform a repair, and I am not sure how to find a replacement.

From what I can tell, it seems like the SKU is probably "**2559**" (embedded in the ceramic under the lid and inside the tank).

Underneath the lid, the ceramic also says "**MADE IN USA**."

Furthermore, inside the tank, underneath the possible SKU, it says "**3 1 95**" (embedded in the ceramic as well). I am assuming that this might be the Manufacture Date (but I am not certain).

I thought that I remembered seeing American Standard somewhere on the toilet, but upon close inspection, I cannot find the logo anywhere. I am not sure if it faded away, or if I am missing it, or if it is a false memory.

When I list the dimensions below, I am considering the width to be left-to-right when viewing the toilet from the front, and the depth is front-to-back (towards the wall).

**Tank Lid Dimensions:**

- W: 20.5 in
- D: 8 in
- H: 1 - 2 in

**Tank Dimensions:**

- W (Top): 19.5 in
- W (Bottom): 18.5 in
- D (Top): 7.25 - 7.5 in
- D (Bottom): 6.5 - 7 in
- H: 11.5 in

The openings for the two tank bolt holes are slightly larger than 1 in, and the distance between the center of each of these holes is about 1 foot (12 in) apart from left-to-right.

The hole for the flush valve is 2 in wide, and the hex-shaped lock nut surrounding this hole in 3 in wide.

For the rest of the toilet (without the tank), the height from the floor to the top of the upper bowl cover is 15.5 - 16 in; the width of the widest part of the bowl (from left-to-right) is 14 - 14.5 in; and the depth (from front-to-back) of the bowl looks to be about 2 ft (24 in).

Any idea what the Make/Model of this tank is, or how I can replace it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is a fool's errand. Unless you have an emotional attachment to that toilet, replace it. I highly recommend an adult size (elongated bowl at 17" seat height) unless you're of alternative stature. Once you've owned those the old size seems like something you'd find in an elementary school.

Comment: Any markings on the *bowl* half of the toilet?

Answer (score 2):

The 3  1  95  indicates that the toilet was manufactured in 1995.

Toilets are all made to fit a standard toilet base, with the anchor bolts 12 inches from the wall.  ( A few models can be found to fit bolt spacing closer to the wall,like 10 inches, but that is an exception.)  Water hook up is always on the right side of the toilet, ( as you would be sitting on it)

Any standard toilet will fit to be a replacement for whatever brand toilet you have.   Finding parts such as the bowl or tank is more time consuming than purchasing a new toilet.  As stated by others, a new toilet can be purchased for very reasonable cost or you can go with something that has all the bells and whistles for much more.

Bottom line is that the bargain basement toilet from your local home store will be a replacement for your current toilet.  Just be sure to use a new seal between the toilet and floor flange.

Comment: The term "toilet base" can be confused with the lower portion of the toilet, as opposed to the toilet _flange_. I suggest revision for clarity. Also, how do you know which way I sit on a toilet?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be American Standard, as you say, simply because they are so ubiquitous, but I don't know. You could try googling, "replacement toilet tank" and see what comes up, I would guess that as long as the holes line up, anything will work, I assume they are reasonable standardized. I wonder if its even worth it though, as a new toilet can be bought for 150 bucks, and will use a lot less water then that old 3.5 gal.